# How to make a website like apple.com/mac?

Tags: web-services, web-frameworks

I know some javascript, html and css. However, i have no idea how could they make some website like http://apple.com/mac .

When I look at the source code of that sites, it looks like being generated by some program/ IDE. I guess people doesn't write all the code by their own using notepad in this case?

Can you suggest how people usually do (what steps/ tools/ IDE...) in order to start making a website like apple.com/mac ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are an amateur website developer, I suggest using Dreamweaver as its WYSIWYG editor and also HTML5 / CSS3 support is great. If you want to stay just code editing, I'd advise Aptana Studio 3, again great code support. As for creating a site like Apple, it's a bit specific. Check out sites like http://net.tutsplus.com/ for tutorials on how to make sites.

How does the code look generated? Some JS is compressed - check out http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/ for an example.

To make sure you start off on the right end of the website developer spectrum check out:

http://html5boilerplate.com/

http://css3pie.com/

http://www.modernizr.com/

Also:

http://jquery.com

http://lesscss.org/

I'm missing out loads more here, there is so much to know. Don't focus on making a site like Apples, it sucks.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first go yo the webpage!
Then right click and click view page source. Then type Control-A then type Control-C then put the code into your code then it will look like it (If you want to edit it change the code) Then you will have a webpage looking like the apple/mac page!

Comment: You need more than just the HTML, at the minimum you'd be missing the CSS stuff as well as any javascript functionality.